# require 'RMagick' raise error 'undefined symbol: XStringListToTextProperty'

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I have:

- Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
- ruby 1.9.1
- ImageMagick 6.8.6-5
- RMagick 2.13.2

When I try to do `require 'RMagick'` in `irb` I have an error:

```
LoadError: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.so: undefined symbol: XStringListToTextProperty - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.so
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
from (irb):1
from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple: just remove `imagemagick` **completely!**

Instead `apt-get remove imagemagick` use next steps:

```
wget imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
tar zxvf ImageMagick.tar.gz
cd ImageMagick-6.8.2-10
./configure
make uninstall
```